# How to convert nominal data to numeric in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, enumerate, data-preprocessing

I am using a binary classification dataset. I want to convert nominal data to numeric. what should I do?

```
age | class
------------
 1 |  no
 2 |  yes
 3 |  no
 4 |  yes
 5 |  no
 6 |  no
 7 |  no
 8 |  yes
 9 |  no
10 |  y
```

**Code:**

```
mapping = {label:idx for idx,label in enumerate(np.unique(['class']))}
df['class'] = df['class'].map(mapping)
```

desired output : {'no':0 'yes':1}

Comment: is the `y` in your 10th row supposed to be `yes` or is it intentional?

Comment: @meowulf It's intentional (for example it's noisy data)

Comment: `df['class'] = df['class'].isin(['yes','y']).astype(int)` should work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem with your code is this:

```
np.unique(['class'])
```

You are trying to find the unique values of the list `['class']`, which is only a single value, you should change it to:

```
np.unique(df['class'])
```

which has all the different values of your `class` column

But before that, you should replace your noisy data `y` to `yes`:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].replace('y', 'yes')
```

The `mapping` variable now has your desired output:

```
{'no':0 'yes':1}
```

Complete code:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'y'],columns=['class'])

df['class'] = df['class'].replace('y', 'yes') # replace your noisy data
mapping = {label:idx for idx,label in enumerate(np.unique(df['class']))} # make your mapping dict
df['class'] = df['class'].map(mapping) # map your class
```

Comment: thank you, It works but if I have multiple nominal data what should I do? this code doesn't work?  mapping = {label:idx for idx,label in enumerate(np.unique(df['class','class2']))}
df['class','class2'] = df['class','class2'].map(mapping)

Comment: what do you mean by multiple nominal data? also what is this `class2` you are talking about? please edit your post and make it clearer for your problem

Comment: I have a question for you, does this only answer binary variables? That is, if we have noise data, I have to delete it first and then do this?

Comment: this works with multi class, however for your noisy data you should replace them first, see my edited answer

Comment: @meowlf Please advise me what should I do if I have a missing value in the dataset to convert it to a number?

Comment: you can try dropping them by `df = df.dropna()`

Comment: But my goal is to fill theme with KNN method. because of that first I should convert data to numeric. Is my method wrong?

Comment: I don't know. You can provide more information by asking a new question with your current problem.